# Keep only first 60 characters of a string

Tags: c#, string, substring, trim

Guys I have a string in `Model.Products[i].Description`. Of unknown length.

I want to have only the first 60 characters of it in a variable.

```
  var data = Model.Products[i].Description;
  var temp = string.Join(string.Empty,data.Take(60));
```

Gives me a null value exception error.
What did I do wrong ?

Any help ?

Comment: All the answers here are ignoring the problem. `data` is `null` here. Debug your program and make sure that `Model.Products[i].Description` is _not null_.

Comment: :) The data is not null.

Comment: Can you post the _actual full exception_ then? Perhaps `Model` is `null`, `Products` is `null`, or `Products[i]` is `null` (or depending on what type `Products` is, perhaps `i` is `null`)

Comment: This question is pretty vague. There are all kinds of simplifications you could make in order to present a simpler problem. Replace `Model.Products[i].Description` with `"abcdefghijklmnop"`. Replace 60 with 6. Does it still give you a null exception? You shouldn't be asking a question here until you have exhausted all your ideas, then ask the simplest question possible. Don't be lazy, this is basic debugging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**Note**: you need to check you input's length

```
string data = Model.Products[i].Description;
string temp = string.Empty;
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data) && data.Length >= 60)
   temp = data.Substring(0,60);
else
   temp = data;
```

Comment: Cheers solved the issue. +1

Comment: @NishantRambhojun: Then `data` _was_ `null`; this is the only possible explanation given the changes made here.

Comment: @NishantRambhojun as said, the data was null and that's why you should always check if your strings are null before manipulating them.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
var temp = data.Substring(0, Math.Min(data.Length, 60));
```

If the length of the string is less then 60 it will take the length of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, you actually used the method name as a tag on your question, you were so close ;)

```
var trim = data.Length > 60 ? 60 : data.Length;
data.Substring(0, trim);
```

Comment: this should not work if length is less then 60 then give Exception like Index and length must refer to a location within the string.

Comment: Error: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.

Comment: +1 to @DhavalPatel, updated my answer to be more robust

Answer (score 1):

All the answers here are ignoring the problem. `data` is `null` here. Debug your program and make sure that `Model.Products[i].Description` is *not null*.

Your current method to get the first 60 characters is a bit obtuse, but *correct*. The problem is you're retrieving invalid data before you even start trying to get the 60 characters.

*If* a `null` value is considered valid for you (that is, you *expect* it to be `null` sometimes) then you need to do a null check first then decide what you want to do. Do you want `temp` to be `null` or an empty string?

---

Here is sample code performing the check, not ideal code but designed to demonstrate the problem:

```
string data = Model.Products[i].Description;
string temp;
if (data == null)
{
    temp = //? what do you want "temp" to be if data is null?
}
else
{
    temp = string.Join(string.Empty,data.Take(60));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp = data.Substring(0, 60);
```

**NOTE**: check if string (i.e. data) is `null or empty` and its length prior to calling Substring method.

Following is example (As stated in other valid answers)

```
string temp = string.Empty;
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data) && data.Length >= 60)
   temp = data.Substring(0,60);
else
   temp = data;
```

Comment: this should not work if length is less then 60 then it shoule give exception like Index and length must refer to a location within the string.

Answer (score 0):

you are using `string.Empty` which is null, try:

```
if (data.Length>=60)
{
  temp=data.Substring(0,60);
}
```

Comment: `String.Empty` is _not null_. It is `""`

Comment: Yes thats true indeed